# How do I make a return statement for the length of parameter[word]?

Tags: javascript, parameters

Make a return statement for the length of parameter `word`

```js
module.exports = function x1(word) {
     return x1.length;
};


module.exports = function x1(word) {
     var w = x1.length
     return w;
};
```

I have tried both and neither are giving me any kind of result.

Comment: `return word.length`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are counting is not "word". Try this:

```
module.exports = function x1(word) {
     return word.length;
};
```